# Remember search sorting if the query text is changed

Tags: feature-request

If I enter something into the search field it will either be recognized as a popular tag (in which case I get a tag search with "newest" sorting) or it will be kept as search text and I get sorting by relevance. Which makes sense but sometimes I change sorting, look at the results and then modify the search text - and it is very annoying that this gives me the default sorting again.

Consider the following scenario: somebody is looking for a recent answer by a keyword that he remembers. For example, he searches for [bubbles](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=bubbles), switches from "relevance" to "newest" - and realizes that it was the wrong keyword. So the search text on the search result page is changed to [bubble](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=bubble&submit=search), search is restarted - oops, the first list entries are several months old again, changing sort order again is required.

Would it be possible to add a hidden field to the search form on the search results page that would store the current value of the `tab` parameter? A new search would then reuse the same sorting as the one already chosen.